# Dúvida com Concat no Oracle

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Estou com um problema na exportação de dados para o Excel, o número gravado no banco e muito grande gerando vários  carácteres estranhos na conversão que o Excel tenta fazer, por isso preciso enviar ele
assim:'51150547067525018740550080000038621721439107'

> Valor Original : 51150547067525018740550080000038621721439107

Como eu poderia ter está saída?

```
select  CONCAT( CAST (nf.chave AS VARCHAR(255)),'*')  from NF nf
```

> Resultado atual: 51160307053693005199550510000032181665018130*

Comment: @gato, qual foi o problema da pergunta?

Comment: Não foi eu que negativei, apenas editei sua pergunta.

Comment: @gato, ok, eu já estou acostumado, tanto que tenho outras opções que passei a utilizar mais devido a isso, já está ficando desgastante utilizar o forum

Comment: Qual foi o valor original, que após formatado, gerou o resultado citado?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, ajustei a pergunta

Comment: Então o que precisa fazer é remover o asterisco no final e colocar entre aspas simples?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, eu gostaria que tivesse aspas simples dois dois lados, coloquei o * porque desta forma o Excel não consegue alterar o formato do campo

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, encontrei a solução, mais agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para o problema:

```
select  ''''|| nvl(nf.chave, '-')||''''  from NF nf
```

Desta forma tenho o resultado:

> '51160307053693005199550510000032181665018130'